# How to Write dataframe to presto/hive using Rstudio

Tags: r, database, hive, rstudio, presto

I am trying to append a `dataframe` which I have in `R` to a table which I have already created in `presto`.

The connection is established, however I am not sure how to `append` the data to the table through `R`.

I have used the `RPresto` library but couldn't find any useful functions.